# Which one is the official Qt SDK (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, nokia

I found a few websites to download the Qt SDK:

1. [Nokia.com](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html)
2. [Qt-Project.org](http://qt-project.org/downloads)
3. [Digia.com](http://qt.digia.com/Try-Qt-Now/)

I can't guess which one is the official SDK. The one from Nokia is even above 1GB, but the one from Qt-Project is only a few hundred MB. And the last one from Digia requires a purchase.

Comment: Qt-Project is the official open source one. It says so and is linked from the Digia site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Nokia used to own Qt, so that **was** the official place to get it.
2. qt-project.org is where you will find the open source licensed versions and source code.
3. The commercial part was sold to Digia. If you want a commercial license, that would be your location.

Basically ignore the Nokia stuff now, and choose the appropriate package for your needs, whether it is just the libraries, or the complete SDK including Qt Creator and the extra dev tools.

Comment: Mind you, you don't need a 'commercial license' to actually use Qt in commercial software (the name is a bit confusing), as the open source version is licensed under the LGPL (which should be good enough for most use cases). If you want paid for support, or to do things beyond what the LGPL allows (or your lawyers are afraid of it), then the 'commercial' license is the way to go.

Comment: Also, if you need Qt for Nokia products, then obviously Nokia download is the thing to get. Also, I'm not sure, but Nokia's download may be the only way to get bundled MingGW Qt4 for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

1. The Qt SDK delivers a complete toolset for Symbian, MeeGo, and desktop apps. It's a bundle package for various platforms. Old versions from Nokia.
2. This is the open source version. Each platform in a different package.
3. This is the commercial version from Digia.com.

If you are using open source, (2) is the official version.